# How do I create a Scroll Menu in Android

Tags: android

i Started to develop an app just   Similar to an mobile launcher For that i need to do a **scroll-able menu window**.so i needed an window with 24 buttons in **3*8** order,that is *3 button in a row such that 8 raw*, so i needed this window scroll-able **vertically**.
I TRIED THIS

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <Button
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:text="@string/1" />
<Button
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:text="@string/2" />
<Button
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:text="@string/3" />
....................................
 ..............................
 ............................
        <\ScrollView>
```

like this.it won't work

Comment: Use a `GridView` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html with only 3 x 8 buttons you probably won't even need it to scroll unless the buttons are large in which case `GridView` will handle that for you.

Comment: I was looking my own this question after nearly 3 years, now I feel like recycler view was what I needed that day :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You need to create 8 horizontal linear layouts like this, put all 8 within single vertical linear layout and put that main layout with in scrolview. As Scrollview can has only single child.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

// another 7 horizontal layouts as above 

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

But , most convenient way is, create single layout that can host 3 buttons and use a list view to populate them. Too many layouts causes rendering issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Scroll view orientation to vertical and use a linearLayout inside of it.